# Why is my Numpy test code 2X slower than in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, performance

I've been developing a Fresnel coefficient based reflectivity solver in Python and I've hit a bit of a roadblock as the performance in Python + Numpy is 2X slower than in Matlab. I've distilled the problem code into a simple example to show the operation being performed in each case:

**Python Code for test case:**

```
import numpy as np
import time

def compare_fn(i):
    a = np.random.rand(400)
    vec = np.random.rand(400)
    t = time.time()
    for j in xrange(i):
        a = (2.3 + a * np.exp(2j*vec))/(1 + (2.3 * a * np.exp(2j*vec)))
    print (time.time()-t)
    return a

a = compare_fn(200000)
```

> Output: 10.7989997864

**Equivalent Matlab code:**

```
function a = compare_fn(i)

    a = rand(1, 400);
    vec = rand(1, 400);
    tic
    for m = 1:i
        a = (2.3 + a .* exp(2j*vec))./(1 + (2.3 * a .* exp(2j*vec)));
    end
    toc
```

> > > a = compare_fn(200000);
> > >       Elapsed time is 5.644673 seconds.

I'm stumped by this. I already have MKL installed (Anaconda Academic License). I would greatly appreciate any help in identifying the issue with my example if any and how I can achieve equivalent if not better performance using Numpy.

In general, I cannot parallelize the loop as solving the Fresnel coefficients for a multilayer involves a recursive calculation which can be expressed in the form of a loop as above.

Comment: At 200000 runs, I might suspect the garbage collector. Try comparing best times instead of aggregate times. In both cases you should be pulling out common subexpressions if you're going for speed.

Comment: @desiredlogin `2j` creates the imaginary number 0+2i in Matlab (and numpy it seems). `2i` does the same thing. It's just more notation obvious than writing `2*i` and hoping `i` hasn't been defined as something else previously.

Comment: @David just checking (since your loop variable is `j` in the numpy version)

Comment: @U2EF1 - The discrepancy seems to scale with N...even if I drop the number of iterations down to ~ 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing a lot of experimenting to try and determine the source of the speed difference between Matlab and Python/Numpy for the example in my original question. Some of the key findings have been:

1. Matlab now has a JIT compiler that provides significant benefit in situations involving loops. Turning it off reduces performance by 2X making it similar in speed to the native Python + Numpy code.

   feature accel off

   a = compare_fn(200000);

   Elapsed time is 9.098062 seconds.
2. I then began exploring options for optimizing my example function using Numba and Cython to see how much better I could do. The one significant finding for me was that **Numba JIT optimization on an explicit looped calculation was faster than native vectorized math operations on Numpy arrays**. I don't quite understand why this is the case, but I have included my sample code and timing for tests below. I also played with Cython (I'm no expert) and although it was also quicker, Numba was still 2X faster than Cython, so I ended up sticking with Numba for the tests.

Here is the code for 3 equivalent functions. First one is a Numba optimized function with an explicit loop to perform elementwise calculations. Second function is a Python+Numpy function relying on Numpy vectorization to perform calculations. The third function tries to use Numba to optimize the vectorized Numpy code (and fails to improve as you can see in the results). Lastly, I've included the Cython code, though I only tested it for one case.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nb.complex128[:](nb.int16, nb.int16))
def compare_fn_jit(i, j):
    a = np.asarray(np.random.rand(j), dtype=np.complex128)
    vec = np.random.rand(j)
    exp_term = np.exp(2j*vec)

    for k in xrange(i):
        for l in xrange(j):
            a[l] = (2.3 + a[l] * exp_term[l])/(1 + (2.3 * a[l] * exp_term[l]))
    return a

def compare_fn(i, j):
    a = np.asarray(np.random.rand(j), dtype=np.complex128)
    vec = np.random.rand(j)
    exp_term = np.exp(2j*vec)
    for k in xrange(i):
        a = (2.3 + a * exp_term)/(1 + (2.3 * a * exp_term))
    return a

compare_fn_jit2 = nb.jit(nb.complex128[:](nb.int16, nb.int16))(compare_fn)


import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def compare_fn_cython(int i, int j):
    cdef int k, l
    cdef np.ndarray[np.complex128_t, ndim=1] a, vec, exp_term
    a = np.asarray(np.random.rand(j), dtype=np.complex128)
    vec = np.asarray(np.random.rand(j), dtype=np.complex128)
    exp_term = np.exp(2j*vec)

    for k in xrange(i):
        for l in xrange(j):
            a[l] = (2.3 + a[l] * exp_term[l])/(1 + (2.3 * a[l] * exp_term[l]))
    return a
```

Timing Results:

i. Timing for a single outer loop - Demonstrates efficiency of vectorized calculations

> %timeit -n 1 -r 10 compare_fn_jit(1,1000000) 1 loops, best of 10: 352
>   ms per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 10 compare_fn(1,1000000) 1 loops, best of 10: 498 ms
>   per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 10 compare_fn_jit2(1,1000000) 1 loops, best of 10: 497
>   ms per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 10 compare_fn_cython(1,1000000) 1 loops, best of 10:
>   424 ms per loop

ii. Timing in extreme case of large loops with calculations on short arrays (expect Numpy+Python to perform poorly)

> %timeit -n 1 -r 5 compare_fn_jit(1000000,40) 1 loops, best of 5: 1.44
>   s per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 5 compare_fn(1000000,40) 1 loops, best of 5: 28.2 s
>   per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 5 compare_fn_jit2(1000000,40) 1 loops, best of 5: 29 s
>   per loop

iii. Test for somewhere mid-way between the two cases above

> %timeit -n 1 -r 5 compare_fn_jit(100000,400) 1 loops, best of 5: 1.4 s
>   per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 5 compare_fn(100000,400) 1 loops, best of 5: 5.26 s
>   per loop
>
> %timeit -n 1 -r 5 compare_fn_jit2(100000,400) 1 loops, best of 5: 5.34
>   s per loop

As you can see, using Numba can improve efficiency by a factor ranging from 1.5X - 30X for this particular case. I am truly impressed with how efficient it is and how easy it is to use and implement when compared against Cython.

Answer (score 3):

The following is similar to unutbu's deleted answer, and for your sample input runs 3x faster on my system. It will probably also run faster if you implement it like this in Matlab, but that's a different story. To be able to use ipython's `%timeit` functionality I have rewritten your original function as:

```
def fn(a, vec, i):
    for j in xrange(i):
        a = (2.3 + a * np.exp(2j*vec))/(1 + (2.3 * a * np.exp(2j*vec)))
    return a
```

And I have optimized it by removing the exponential calculation from the loop:

```
def fn_bis(a, vec, n):
    exp_vec = np.exp(2j*vec)
    for j in xrange(n):
        a = (2.3 + a * exp_vec) / (1 + 2.3 * a * exp_vec)
    return a
```

Taking both approaches for a test ride:

```
In [2]: a = np.random.rand(400)

In [3]: vec = np.random.rand(400)

In [9]: np.allclose(fn(a, vec, 100), fn_bis(a, vec, 100))
Out[9]: True

In [10]: %timeit fn(a, vec, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.43 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit fn_bis(a, vec, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.57 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit fn(a, vec, 200000)
1 loops, best of 3: 16.9 s per loop

In [13]: %timeit fn_bis(a, vec, 200000)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.25 s per loop
```

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I overlooked that. Yes, that will certainly help improve things. However, I'm still curious about the overall performance difference between the two. Is Python going to be inherently slower in loop situations compared to Matlab? I was hoping that isn't the case.

Comment: Update - Nevermind, I went back and in the Fresnel calculations, vec changes in each loop so it has to be recalculated. The only saving I could gain is by calculating it once and storing in a local variable which I then reference within the formula.

Comment: We can do a little better. `exp_vec = np.exp(2j*vec); k = 1/2.3; k25 = 1/2.3**.25; for _ in xrange(n): a = k + k25/(k + a * exp_vec)`. Not sure if I can get the number of primitive operations lower. And of course in your loop you should be calculating `a * exp_vec` only once.

Comment: Benchmarking with storing `a*exp_vec` in a temporary variable provides another 10% in performance for this problem.

Comment: @ebarr - The problem is that in my real world program, a and vec both change every loop, so caching them wouldn't provide a great deal of benefit. I am planning on running a bunch of comparison tests between Matlab and Numpy/Python to try and isolate the source of the timing difference. Will post an update when I do so.

Comment: @HamsterHuey Although `a*exp_vec` changes between loops, it does not change in a loop. Therefore you can replace `a = (2.3+a*exp_vec)/(1+2.3*a*exp_vec)` with `z=a*exp_vec; a=(2.3+z)/(1+2.3*z)` Doing this gave me a 10% speed improvement.

Comment: @ebarr Sorry, yes you are right. I think I read U2EF1's response and replied to you instead. Caching that factor at the beginning of each loop does help a LOT. Weirdly enough, after some more tweaking my Fresnel solver is 1.5X faster in Python than Matlab, but I can't get that same benefit in these simplified tests to isolate the source of the performance differential. I am going to experiment some more tonight and will respond later with an update on where things stand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if numpypy is far enough along yet for what you're doing, but you might try it.

http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks interesting but probably not something I'm going to depend on till it matures a bit more.